# AForge.Video : Mouse Cursor not visible in recording

Tags: c#, wpf, aforge, video-recording

I am using one built app which is recording computer screen. I am extending it with some more features like record only active session and I am successful in doing this.

But after I realize the mouse cursor is not recording. you can see below link the sample of recording.

https://vimeo.com/262190965

I am using Aforge.Video library.

Please, anyone, help me out. Otherwise, my all effort will be countless.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include

Comment: Does 
http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Bonsai.Video/2.1.0/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5/Bonsai.Video/Bonsai.Video/ScreenCaptureStream.cs?ImageName=Bonsai.Video help?

Comment: Thanks, @mjwills I will review this code.

Comment: I did achieved this issue by writing external image on screen with respect to cursor movement.